# My Apple Watch is getting notifications but my phone is not alerting with any notifications

Tags: iphone, notifications, apple-watch

This is really frustrating.  I get the alerts on my watch but not on my phone.  This is especially frustrating when I'm driving.  When I get an alert, its easier to view it on my mounted phone versus reading my arm.  Is there a way to get notifications at both places?

Answer (score 2):

Nope. AFAIK, at least as an Apple Watch owner, if you have an Apple Watch paired then you will receive all notifications on it. I don't believe that there is a way to change so that you receive notifications on the Watch and in Notification Center on your iPhone at the same time.

Comment: Thanks.  The stupid thing is these notifications show up on my lock screen but no sound and no waking up screen.

Comment: Only way to receive the notifications on your iphone is by unlocking your iphone and keep your screen on (prevent it from going to sleep).