# Why is my apple watch stealing notifications from my iphone?

Tags: apple-watch

On my iPhone I have calendar alerts notifications turned on with the following boxes checked.

- “Lock Screen”
- “Notification Center”
- “Banners”

If I have an appointment with a 15 minute alert, then 15 minutes before the appointment, there is a faint vibration from on my watch and, if the watch’s screen happens to be on, the notification appears there.

But my iphone just sits there like a lump.  There is no vibration or sound.

If my watch is not on my wrist, the opposite is the case.  The alert comes to the phone but not the watch.

In both cases, I’m seeing nothing on my ipad.

I suspect that this is true for most notifications, not just calendar alerts.

Why is this happening and how can I set it up so that all alerts come all devices?

Comment: Are you acknowledging or clearing the alert on your watch when you receive it?

Comment: Do you have calendar alerts on your iPad?

Comment: @allan No, I'm not clearing the alert on the watch.

Comment: @Ezekiel  No, alerts calendar alerts were turned off on the ipad.  That's fine.  I just want the Apple Watch and IPhone to both work.  Although, if I did turn on calendar alerts on the ipad, I would hope that they appear and wouldn't interfere with alerts on any other devices.

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/223298/my-apple-watch-is-getting-notifications-but-my-phone-is-not-alerting-with-any-no?rq=1 from 7 years ago.  But, you know, things may have changed.  It seems ridiculous that having a watch downgrades the phone.  (I miss my Pebble watch.)